# Wordpress Loop with different Column sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a loop that does the following,

The first post is a different column size, and every post under that is a col 6.

I'm using bootstrap. this image shows what i'm trying to accomplish.
So each NEW posts shows at the top in the full column and everytime you create a new post it pushes down into the 1/2 columns.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Are you adding this to an archive template or using a custom query and a new instance if WP_Query?  Assuming you are using Bootstrap 4?  Add the associated template (or filter) code to your question and I can write up a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't provide the full code solution, but I will give you the direction to solve your problem.

There are two ways to solve your problem:

1. Use two separated loop, the first one will have `posts_per_page` set to `1`. The second one will have `offset` set to `1`. It does the job but not optimal solution.
2. Use only one loop with a counter:

   - Set a `$counter` to `1` outside the `while` loop.
   - Increase `$counter` for `1` at the end of `while` loop, so it will increase every loop in `while` loop.
   - Check for current value of `$counter` before you echo the template

     - if `$counter = 1`, print the template for your featured post.
     - else? print the template for normal post (1/2 col)
   - You may need a wrapper for 2 column layout, you can print the opening `div` when you check for `$counter = 1`, right after the featured markup. For closing `div`, you can print it after the `while` loop end.

If you have any question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should check inside a loop for an index and then change element class dynamically.

```
$args = array();
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $colNumber = $query->current_post > 0 ? 'col-6' : 'col-12';

        printf('<div class="%s">%s</div>', $colNumber, get_the_title());
    }
}
```

Hope it helps